# Actionscript file not found when trying to compile a flash movie

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am using a PC and my consultant is on a Mac.  I have sent her my working files along with a folder of referenced .as files.  For some reason, when she goes to compile her movie it gives an error that the referenced .as file cannot be found.  It works fine on my machine.

I have double and triple checked to ensure she has all the correct files within the correct local directories so I am completely stumped.  I am using Flash CS4 and she is on CS5 - does anyone have any ideas for us?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you guys are on the same page with source paths etc - the .fla is in the same place relative to the .as files on both systems, right? That's the first thing I'd double check.

One other detail, though, could cause this problem. If you sent her a .zip file including all of the files and she is on Windows 7, it's possible that she's opened the .fla file directly from the zip without extracting anything. Windows 7 treats compressed files like folders, so it would seem like everything should work - but in actuality, the other files would still be compressed and inaccessible to the compiler.

The solution would be to make sure that she has extracted everything out of the zip file into a new parent folder.

That's sort of an edge case, but I've seen it happen!

Comment: Hey Myk :)  Yes, I am positive that our source files are in the exact directory.  I provided all the files via FTP so the zip file wasn't the issue, I even had her send me a zip file with the updated documents and I was able to export it no problem....  I am so stumped on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean by 'referenced .as file'. Do you use any external libraries or pre-installed components?

Maybe Papervision, Tweener, or some other stuff that your consultant doesn't have but you do?

If you could check out your 'Advanced ActionScript' settings under 'Publish Settings' for some references what Libraries your application uses.

If you could drop here what file exactly is not found would get further.

Regards,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can think of are if you have used any paths with \ in them in the publish settings or such. That won't work on the Mac, it needs / in file paths.

Another possible cause for a project to work on one machine and not another is if you have library paths or such defined in your Flash CS4 preferences, rather than in the project/fla file.

Comment: Lars, that was a great suggestion regarding the "\" vs "/" but here is the example of the actionscript that is used to find the external .as file: "import gs.dataTransfer.XMLParser;"  - does the mac require that I add a file extension?

Comment: No,that should be fine. import statements in the code are "cross platform", the \ vs / in paths are not a problem in code, but can sometimes be in publish settings for the fla file.

Comment: In fact, by default the Flash IDE uses the Mac native : as a separator, if you add your target path by browsing to the directory.  This will not work on Windows, of course.  Also, the IDE usually inserts the absolute path to the linked directory, so the referenced files won't even be found on another Mac unless your HD has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using capital letters in your filenames and referencing them incorrectly, as windows ignores them and as osx is a unix based operating system doesnt.